# c# ler varios xml de nfe

Tags: c#, xml

Boa tarde, não estou conseguindo ler a tag de CST (ICMS) de um xml de nfe!

```
<ICMS>
  <ICMS00>
    <orig>1</orig>
    <CST>00</CST>
    <modBC>3</modBC>
    <vBC>390.70</vBC>
    <pICMS>4.0000</pICMS>
    <vICMS>15.62</vICMS>
  </ICMS00>
```

```
if (meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "ICMS00") 
    icms = "icms";
if (icms =="icms" && meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "CST")
{
    cst_icms_csosn = meuxml.ReadElementString();
}

if (meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "PIS")
    tipoImposto = "PIS";
else if (meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "COFINS")
    tipoImposto = "COFINS";

if (tipoImposto == "PIS" && meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "CST")
{
    cst_pis = meuxml.ReadElementString();
}
else if (tipoImposto == "COFINS" && meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "CST")
{
    // cst_cofins = meuxml.ReadElementString();
    cst_cofins = cst_pis;
    tag = "/det";
}
```

Comment: Amigo, tu poderias dar mais detalhes? Um exemplo de código que reproduza o problema, quais os erros que estão acontecendo...

Comment: oi não apresenta erro, apenas não lê os arquivos xml

Comment: o codigo que da o "erro" eu coloquei seria a parte do icms, coloquei a parte do pis/cofins para facilitar pois ambos possuem um elemento CST.if (meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "ICMS00") 
    icms = "icms";
if (icms =="icms" && meuxml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && meuxml.Name == "CST")
{
    cst_icms_csosn = meuxml.ReadElementString();
}